# Aws-Cdk automatically input values

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cdk

Is it possible to automatically set some values in my Cloudformation template with AWS-CDK?

For Example:

making a calculation and automatically adjusting the Autoscale CPU average

Answer (score 1):

Of course, as long as you are performing the calculations synchronously.
This is because CDK is designed to be deterministic.
Also, don't forget that CDK is a tool for provisioning and not for changing values while the application is running.

I do not know Your usecase, but You can do something like this:

```js
const cpu = new CPU(this, 'example-logical-cpu-id', {average: performAutoscalingCalculation()})
```

This won't work:

```js
const cpu = new CPU(this, 'example-logical-cpu-id', {average: await performAutoscalingCalculation()})
```